# Ma -> (a -> Mb) -> Mb ... vs ... Ma -> (a -> b) -> b

Tags: monoid, monads

I am a newbie to the functional programming world. Is there a reason why in all example I found so far about Monad (or should I say Monoid) is written as:

```
Ma -> (a -> Mb) -> Mb
```

instead of

```
Ma -> (a -> b) -> b
```

Comment: That is simply the definition. Why should it be one way or another? It depends on what you intend to do with it.

Comment: So, the second is not a Monad because of definition, right?

Comment: My question is actually about why we have this definition not covering the second example.